# Question about *Cryptosporidium hominis*

Tags: parasitology, parasitism

*Cryptosporidium muris* infects mostly rodents and it is usually found in gastric gladns. *Cryptosporidium parvum* infects humans and certain animals and it is found in the terminal ileum and colon.

There is also *Cryptosporidium hominis* that infects only humans. My question is

> where exactly in the human gastrointestinal tract it resides?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/crypto/pathogen.html) seems to indicate that it adheres to the epithelium of different internal organs. They write:

> The sporozoites are released and parasitize epithelial cells (b, c) of the gastrointestinal tract or other tissues such as the respiratory tract.

Here is the figure from that page:

[image]